# How to save an .xlsx file to Downloads folder in Android?

Tags: java, kotlin, file-io

I'm working on an application in which an .xlsx file is generated and saved to a directory on the user's Android device. At present, the file is being saved to data/package/files/logs/filename.xlsx, where I originally specified it should be saved, but I decided I want them to save into the Downloads folder.

Here is my issue - no matter how I try to save the file, it is always saving to that directory, and none of what I've done in pursuit of saving the file where I want to has gotten me close to where I want to be.

This is the code I'm currently using to create the path for the file to be saved at in the application directory I outlined:

```
val path: File? = getExternalFilesDir(null)
val logDirectory = File(path, "logs")
val file = File(logDirectory, filePath)
```

I've tried out:

```
 Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

...as well as all relevant functions using environment variables.

All I want is to be able to open up my phone's file browser, tap on the Downloads folder, and see my exported .xlsx file, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong that is keeping me from being able to achieve this. Is there something major I'm missing?

Comment: Q: Where is the "Downloads folder" in Android?  A: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);` Which is exactly what you're doing.  Q: what problem(s) are you having?